# cloud function - firestore: event.data.toJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

according to the docs it looks like `event.data` passed to auth.user().onCreate 
 should be a `UserRecord`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#access_user_attributes
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord

But in my cloud function if i do `event.data.toJSON()` i get

> TypeError: event.data.toJSON is not a function

I want to write the data to a firestore. In order to get at the data i have to do

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.data));
```

What is the correct way to get a plain object representation of the user data?

Comment: doesn't this const user = event.data; work directly?

Comment: no unfortunately it does not.

Comment: The `event.data` implementation is different than the Firebase Admin SDK implementation which explains why this was missed. It should be fixed. In the meantime , you could just use the Admin SDK and call `getUser` with the `uid` provided from the event data. That would return the `UserRecord` with the `toJSON` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the SDK to me. I have raised an issue with the team.

IMO the workaround until this is fixed is to copy the values into a plain JavaScript object and use that to add to Firestore.

Comment: why data is not getting when using event.data.data() in cloud firestore triggers